# Python runserver error loading MySQLDB module: undefined symbol: mysql_kill

Tags: python, mysql, django, vagrant, puppet

I'm receiving the following when trying to `runserver` after provisioning a VM using Puppet:

`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module> raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysql_kill`

I found [this discussion](http://petrkout.com/linux/a-solution-to-the-python2-7site-packages_mysql-so-undefined-symbol-mysql_kill-error/), but the suggestion there didn't help. I'd really appreciate any assistance! `pip freeze` reveals that I have `MySQL-python==1.2.5` installed. I also have `libmysqlclient-dev` installed via `apt-get`. Installing `python-mysqldb` via `apt-get` doesn't seem to have any effect on this problem.

Comment: Did you try the solution in the comment section of your link?

Comment: try `apt-get remove python-mysqldb` and `pip install --upgrade MySQL-python` If that does not work, we'd probably need more info on your provisioning (also ubuntu version) to be able to replicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frederic Henri's response is correct. I had a mistake in my Puppet provisioning that resulted in mysql-python *not* being updated, but also without throwing an error during that step.